# What is the exact definition of a dictionary in the concept of linear algebra and computer science?

Tags: terminology, image-processing, linear-algebra

I am reading [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379505003459) for my master thesis and trying to understand every concept in it. The following sentence confuses me as to what is the exact definition of a dictionary in this concept except for the fact that it holds the atoms as its columns?

> Recall we refer to the columns of the matrix $A$ as *atoms* that are later used as building blocks in the construction of $b$. Such a matrix that holds the atoms as its columnsis referred to as a dictionary[...].

Comment: not sure where this use originated but maybe in LSA type apps? take a look at [bag of words model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as it says, a "dictionary" is just the word they're using for a matrix with entries of a particular type that's used for a particular purpose. They're drfining the term "dictionary" in the text you quote.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw that definition, just wanted to know if there are any other properties.

Comment: They could also be using "dictionary" as a synonym for "Codebook"